# JS Error on HTML5 / jQuery Productdesigner within a Shopsystem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to implement a product designer in a eCommerce-System (Shopware 4).

I just want do add it within the template, without a "real" connection to the Shopsystem. The connection is coming later. For now i just want to add this tool to the template, so it is usable for testing.

But I get a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Here you can see the designer in a normal HTML file:
http://www.stempel-fabrik24.de/fpd/

and here is the site within the Shopsystem:
http://www.stempel-fabrik24.de/stempel/modico-d-serie/modico-d1

The js and css files are loaded in `<head>` after jQuery. 
The Designer uses .php files these are selected within the tool.

I don’t know why the Function doesn’t load.

Answer (score 0):

Update jQuery.

You are using `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` and call function `jQuery.parseHTML` in `jQuery.fancyProductDesigner.js`

`jQuery.parseHTML` was added in jQuery 1.8: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/